# i moved elasticsearch to new folder also give new path in elasticsearch.yml file but its giving error

Tags: elasticsearch

This is the error I am getting from elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-07-11 08:23:29 UTC; 1h 29min ago
Docs: http://www.elastic.co
Process: 1579 ExecStart=/usr/local/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch (code=exited, status=78)
Main PID: 1579 (code=exited, status=78)
```

This is the log file , this is what i get after using 'journalctl -u elasticsearch.service' command:

```
Jul 11 06:06:26 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Jul 11 06:08:28 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: Stopping Elasticsearch...
Jul 11 06:08:28 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: Stopped Elasticsearch.
Jul 11 06:34:49 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Jul 11 06:35:09 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jul 11 06:35:09 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 11 06:48:00 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Jul 11 06:48:20 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jul 11 06:48:20 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 11 06:52:21 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Jul 11 06:52:42 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jul 11 06:52:42 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 11 06:57:36 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Jul 11 06:57:57 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jul 11 06:57:57 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 11 07:46:36 vyakar-stage-elastic systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Jul 11 07:46:40 vyakar-stage-elastic elasticsearch[726]: [2019-07-11T07:46:40,490][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [fmcn] Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12, r
Jul 11 07:46:40 vyakar-stage-elastic elasticsearch[726]: [2019-07-11T07:46:40,501][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [fmcn] This can result in part of the JVM bei
Jul 11 07:46:40 vyakar-stage-elastic elasticsearch[726]: [2019-07-11T07:46:40,503][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [fmcn] Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 1
Jul 11 07:46:40 vyakar-stage-elastic elasticsearch[726]: [2019-07-11T07:46:40,504][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [fmcn] These can be adjusted by modifying /et
Jul 11 07:46:40 vyakar-stage-elastic elasticsearch[726]:         # allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall
```

Comment: Can you [enable journalctl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html#deb-running-systemd) so we can gather more insights into what's happening?

Comment: done , please check that out

Comment: You seem to be failing this bootstrap check: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_memory_lock_check.html

Comment: I tried but its not working, the thing is initially it was working fine but i want to change the path so i copied the folder from /usr/share/elasticsearch and paste it to /usr/local/elasticsearch(cp -rf /usr/share/elasticsearch/* /usr/local/elasticsearch ) also copied files from /etc/elasticsearch and paste it in /usr/local/elasticsearch/config(cp -rf /etc/elasticsearch/* /usr/local/elasticsearch/config) , also change path in elasticsearch.yml file and more changes i did , so this was the scene and now its not working.

Comment: try `cp -Rf` instead of `cp -rf`

Comment: ok i will try and come back to you, btw thanks for the suggestion.